# Is Python's Requests module adding data to a file that it is posting?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to use the requests module to send a csv file to an API that uploads data into a database.  Since the data is going into a database, the API is configured to reject files that have an unrecognized column name.  The accepted columns are "id", "artist", "video".  I have a test.csv file with just 1 row of data:

```
id,artist,video
1,The Shins,Phantom Limb
```

When I send the file to the api with the following curl request, it goes through successfully.

```
curl -i -u myUser:myPassword -X POST -T .\test.csv "http://destination.com/api/endpoint/create-or-update-records"
```

Here's the curl response message:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 14:47:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

However, when I try to send the file using the requests post method like this:

```
url = "http://destination.com/api/endpoint/create-or-update-records"
files = {'file': open("test.csv", "rb")}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, auth=("myUser","myPassword"))
```

The response I get back is this:

```
Unknown fields: '--5a6f03307ed74747904844625f76a82e'. Valid fields are: 'id', 'artist', 'video'
```

If I send the file again, I get the same message, but the "--lotsofcharacters" is now a difference set of characters.

I'm guessing I'm missing a setting or something, but I have combed the requests API and can't figure out what it is.  What is different between the curl request and the requests request that is causing one to fail, and the other to go through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not posting plain text to your server with requests. The documentation explicitly states that you use the `files` parameter when you wish to perform a `multipart/form-data` upload to the server. In this case all you need to do is

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    r = requests.post(url, data=csv_file, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, auth=('user', 'password'))
```